# Using Appletstub I created AppeltEnvironment and initilized applet but I keep getting Invalid Stream Header

Tags: java, swing, jar, jframe, applet

I have followed below link answer:
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/16095828/5436880

Scenario: I am replicating Website Applet behavior in my Java program, website is https://carelink.minimed.eu/patient/entry.jsp?bhcp=1. I have .Jar file downloaded for a applet. I added it to my Java Project.
Using AppletStub I have passed relevant parameters and called classLoader.
I am able to open applet window

But I am getting error as Invalid Stram Header:0A0A0A0A error

```
public class AppletSnipper{ 

public static void main(String args[]) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException, URISyntaxException, IOException{
    //CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager(null, CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL));


     Connection.Response res = Jsoup.connect("https://carelink.minimed.eu/patient/j_security_check")
             .data("j_username", "REMOVED").data("j_password", "REMOVED").method(Connection.Method.POST)
             .execute();
     Map<String, String> loginCookies = res.cookies();


    //CookieHandler.setDefault((CookieHandler) loginCookies);
    CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager());
    URL url[] = { 
        // new File("/ddmsDTWApplet.jar").toURI().toURL()
            new URL("https://carelink.minimed.eu/patient/main/deviceUpload.do/applets/ddmsDTWApplet.jar").toURI().toURL()


        };


    AppletEnvironment appletEnvironment = new AppletEnvironment(url[0]);




    appletEnvironment.put("width", "715");
    appletEnvironment.put("height", "390");
    appletEnvironment.put("src", "");

    appletEnvironment.put("CODE", "minimed.ddms.applet.dtw.DTWApplet");
    appletEnvironment.put("type","application/x-java-applet;jpi-version=1.6");
    appletEnvironment.put("scriptable","true");
    appletEnvironment.put("cache_option","Plugin");
    appletEnvironment.put("cache_archive","ddmsDTWApplet.jar");
    appletEnvironment.put("archive","ddmsDTWApplet.jar");
    appletEnvironment.put("mayscript","true");
    appletEnvironment.put("userName","abc");
    appletEnvironment.put("password","xyz");
    appletEnvironment.put("locale","en_IN");
    appletEnvironment.put("systemVersion","7333-8.1.019");
    appletEnvironment.put("lastPumpUniqueID","");
    appletEnvironment.put("lastMeterUniqueID","");
    appletEnvironment.put("lastCGMUniqueID","");
    appletEnvironment.put("uploadParadigmLinkMeterOnly","false");
    appletEnvironment.put("uploadCGM","true");
    appletEnvironment.put("uploadG3B","false");
    appletEnvironment.put("ngpUploadBlackList","[MMT-1581, MMT-1582, MMT-1780, MMT-1781, MMT-1782]");
    appletEnvironment.put("hideNGP","N");
    appletEnvironment.put("hideCNL","N");
    appletEnvironment.put("progressbar","true");
    appletEnvironment.put("boxmessage","Loading Device Reader Applet...");
    appletEnvironment.put("troubleshooting","Troubleshooting");
    appletEnvironment.put("boxbgcolor","238,238,238");
    appletEnvironment.put("boxfgcolor","black");









    //Frame frame = new Frame("chikhalehero");


    //DTWApplet appletClass = new DTWApplet();
    URLClassLoader classLoader = new URLClassLoader(url);
    DTWApplet appletClass = (DTWApplet)classLoader.loadClass("minimed.ddms.applet.dtw.DTWApplet").newInstance();

    //appletClass.start();

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));


    appletClass.setName("Custom Applet Name");
    //appletClass.set

    frame.getContentPane().add(appletClass);

    if( appletClass == null )   System.out.println("Not intialiyed.");
    //else  appletClass.init();
    //appletClass.start();



    appletClass.setStub(appletEnvironment);


    appletClass.init();
    appletClass.start();

    frame.pack();
    frame.isResizable();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    System.out.println("I have pressed Sync");



}
```

}

Comment: You posted a username and password in your code above. That was not smart... remove them for your question and immediately change at least the password, or else a hacker might misuse your account.

Comment: Ohh!! I missed the above code lines where I set username and password. I have changed my credentials.
Thanks for the update also the account was for dummy use but anyhow Thanks once again.

Comment: You do realize the stub in the linked question returns a `null` applet context, right? Does the applet use the applet context?

Comment: Finally the King of Applet @AndrewThompson replied t my question. From the past 4 weeks I am searching/ reading about my issue and every question I see, there is always a comment of Andrew. Hey Andrew really need help man, I am stuck with no right way to proceed.

Regarding your question, yes it does return null.
What I could pin down to is that somehow there is a authentication of application and the above code I used does not do any authentication, and that is why I am getting error login into applet and then later on Invalid input stream