# What is invalid stream header: 0A0A0A0A with respect to opening Jar file in Java program

Tags: java, swing, jar, applet

I have a Jar file (Containing applet) which I am trying to open using Jframe. I can open Applet but it gives me invalid stream header: 0A0A0A0A

I am not sure what exactly it means

Comment: What does your code look like? How did you create the jar file containing the applet and how are you opening it? It looks you are trying to read a file which is not a valid jar file.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I have a Jar file downloaded from Website. I am trying to replicate Applet behavior from my Java project. I am till now able to show the applet tab but I am sure Applet uses some protocol which is giving me error

So this is the post i followed http://stackoverflow.com/a/16095828/5436880

Here is the deatiled question I asked. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43842036/using-appletstub-i-created-appeltenvironment-and-initilized-applet-but-i-keep-ge

Comment: “it gives me invalid stream header” is not much information to go on.  If you received an exception, edit your question and paste the *entire* stack trace of that exception (as text, not as an image).